# Using Natural Earth Dataset As WMS

Tags: wms, data

This Question is about [Natural Earth Project](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). I tried to do some research about  creating my own WMS and came across this project. The web page says :

> Natural Earth is a public domain map dataset available at 1:10m,
>   1:50m, and 1:110 million scales. Featuring tightly integrated vector
>   and raster data, with Natural Earth you can make a variety of visually
>   pleasing, well-crafted maps with cartography or GIS software.

How can I harvest the data for my WMS So that it can be used with
    Mapinfo or Other software?

Comment: Hi @kitex. As you have already noted yourself, your post contains more than one question. Please split them into separate questions - each focusing on a single problem. That would be more appropriate for the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: @underdark That would be great but I think all questions are related

Comment: @kitex Although the questions are related; they are not unique in scope. The third question has been discussed on this stack exchange. The first question is a discussion of its own. The idea is that you have one question per post so you'll have one answer per post. Having 3 different questions in the same post, you will not be able to accept 3 answers.

Comment: @underdark I shall split up the question :) . Thanks.

Comment: @underdark I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/naturalearth/index.html  for more details.

Comment: iant - do you have this page anywhere else. I think it might be useful.

Comment: I'll ask them to reboot it for me - in the mean time try http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/geoserver_quickstart.html

Comment: @MattT - it's back!